# How to get the full transaction details in paypal using the payment_id in paypal android sdk

Tags: android, paypal

I am using the ***paypal android sdk 2.14.1***. When I make the payment by the sdk, then it give the following response,

```
{
"response": {
    "state": "approved",
    "id": "PAY-9A140896UE325390DK5VK4KI",
    "create_time": "2016-06-22T15:26:40Z",
    "intent": "sale"
},
"client": {
    "platform": "Android",
    "paypal_sdk_version": "2.14.1",
    "product_name": "PayPal-Android-SDK",
    "environment": "sandbox"
},
"response_type": "payment"
```

}

But I want the **full transaction details**

So please anyone can give the suggestion how to get the **transaction details**. by payment id.

**Note:** I am using **soap** APIs.

Comment: Any Update on this on mobile SDK for Android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer,

First of all we have to generate the **access-Token** by the **client_id** and **secret**,

```
curl -v https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token \
     -H "Accept: application/json" \  
     -H "Accept-Language: en_US" \  
     -u "client_id:secret" \  
     -d "grant_type=client_credentials"
```

After getting the **access-Token** I have to make another api call for getting the full transaction details,

```
curl -v -X GET https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/Payment-Id \
     -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
     -H "Authorization: Bearer Access-Token"
```

After hitting this I will get the full **transaction details**.

For know more go to this [link](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/make-your-first-call/#get-an-access-token).

Comment: Show payment details  --> /v1/payments/payment/payment_id
I tried with this REST Api but it does not return full response all the time. I need a transaction fee but it only returns some times. And I see it returns different response in different state of transaction like Pending/ Approved etc.

Any one have any solution for that to get transaction id all the time?

Answer (score 1):

Send the payment id to server API as:

```
url -v -X GET https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/Payment-Id \

-H "Content-Type:application/json" \

-H "Authorization: Bearer Access-Token"
```

for more details, check [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#payment_get)

Comment: i m using the soap apis first. and Is this access token get it from below url. 


https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications/
If yes while hitting the url with payment_id by terminal, it shows HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized.

Answer (score 0):

Obtain the `"id": "PAY-9A140896UE325390DK5VK4KI"` retruned in the mSDK response, and then look up the payment resource with your server-end REST API. This is also a recommended implementation of verifying the mobile payment for fraud prevention.

Check the procedure here for [Verify a mobile payment](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/mobile/verify-mobile-payment/?mark=validate%20payment)

Comment: Show payment details  --> /v1/payments/payment/payment_id
I tried with this REST Api but it does not return full response all the time. I need a transaction fee but it only returns some times. And I see it returns different response in different state of transaction like Pending/ Approved etc.

Any one have any solution for that to get transaction id all the time?

Answer (score 0):

**Hi here is the solution after the 2 days Research. i was tired on this. now i found the proper solution for this.**

```
import com.squareup.okhttp.MediaType
import com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
import com.squareup.okhttp.Request
import com.squareup.okhttp.Requl̥estBody

val client = OkHttpClient()
    val mediaType: MediaType = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8")!!
    val body: RequestBody = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "grant_type=client_credentials")
    val request: Request = Request.Builder()
        .url("https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token")
        .method("POST", body)
        .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        .addHeader(
            "Authorization",
            "Basic QVgzT24za***********************************lg="
        )
        .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        .build()
    val response = client.newCall(request).execute()
    val jsonObject = JSONObject(response.body().string())
    val accessToken = jsonObject.getString("access_token")
```

***QVgzT24za***********************************lg=***  is here the converted code from **ClientID:SecretID**

```
val clientID = CommonObjects.PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID
    val clientSecret = CommonObjects.PAYPAL_SECRET_ID
    val text = "$cl4ientID:$clientSecret"
    var data = ByteArray(0)
    try {
        data = text.toByteArray(charset("UTF-8"))
    } catch (e: UnsupportedEncodingException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    val base64 =
        Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.NO_WRAP)
```

Now, **base64** =  ***QVgzT24za***********************************lg=***